# Proxy for redis cluster with 3 masters

Tags: proxy, cluster, redis

I have application and redis with one master.
I want to create redis cluster with 3 masters.  Is there something clever proxies to work with such cluster and without fixing application code? Searches in internet not given result.
Please help me with this issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can use HAProxy, it has build-in redis healthchecks and it is transparent for your app (just change connection from redis node to haproxy node). You should check sentinel too for automatic failover.

Comment: I know about HAProxy. HAProxy good work with Master Slave cluster.  Do you work with HAProxy + Redis cluster with multiple masters?